# SimpleCursorTreeAdapter constructor not being called on Android 2.2

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

On Android 2.2 mContext=context (or anything else I put there) is never called. It does work on 2.3+.
Is it a known issue? Is there a workaround?

```
public class ExpListCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
    Context mContext;

    public ExpListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,
            int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
            int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
         super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom,
            childTo);
        mContext=context;
}

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        int id=groupCursor.getInt(DatabasePazienti.ROWID);
        DatabaseTests mDbTests=new DatabaseTests(mContext);
        mDbTests.open();

        Cursor cursor=mDbTests.fetchPatientTests(id);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: is the `ListaPazientiCursorAdapter` the constructor? if so, it should be called `ExpListCursorAdapter (..)` and not `ListaPazientiCursorAdapter`

Comment: The constructor has the same name of the class. I simply renamed the class because it was in Italian, forgetting to rename the constructor too. You can try yourself running on a 2.2 device, you'll see that this issue exists.

Comment: does it shows any error?

Comment: That constructor is getting called just fine on Android 2.2. What exactly does it mean: `mContext = context` is never called?

Comment: But it gives you an warning or an error?And does it appear in the LogCat?

Comment: Added getChildrenCursor method. mContext is null there on 2.2. I can't open DB on constructor because the code isn't executed. Logcat of FC here: http://pastebin.com/XWfYhZca It works on 2.3+

Comment: Please try changing the visibility of the `mContext` to `private` and then test.

Comment: It doesn't work. And if I put, for example, Log.d("constructor","yes") inside constructor, it never gets executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` in the API 2.2 is different from API 2.3. 
As you can see in here:

API 2.2

> http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java

API 2.3

> http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java

When you use API 2.2 it says `mContext = context` is never called due to the sequence of the methods that are called in the constructor.

Comment: There are two issues with your answer:
1) doing as you says breaks ExpandableListView because there isn't group cursor anymore, so no groups are displayed
2) it doesn't answer the main question: a workaround for the not-executed code in constructor only on Android 2.2

Comment: i have updated the answer. although it has no workround hope it helps you understand why this behaviour is happening

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that is an Android 2.2 bug (even if I couldn't find any reference of it). I included SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java from Android 2.3.3 in my package and now it works.